# How to resolve The method addView(View, int, LinearLayout.LayoutParams) of type YourLayout must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, overriding, supertype

I've already tried setting the java sdk version to 1.6(It was already set correctly).  I've also tried cleaning the project as well as restarting eclipse.

My definition appears correct as I used eclipse's Source > Override/Implement Methods create the methods from subclasses ViewGroup.

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

Looks like somehow you imported `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and ViewGroup does not have a method with a signature like that.

[ViewGroup.addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Make sure your method is using the right kind of `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that eclipse generated code that it didn't like.  I suspect when it generated the code it assumed that LayoutParams was LinearLayout.LayoutParams(I was subclassing LinearLayout).  Explicitly setting layout params to ViewGroup.Layout params did resolve the problem.